# How to add new view in already existing components in Joomla3.3

Tags: joomla3.3

I am using joomla 3.3.x version. In this joomla version one built in component is there for registration and login.That component name is com_user. I have to create two registration forms for my site.

Form names are Registration and Client Registration.

For registration I will use the registration form already present in this component. 
File Structure for this:

```
//joomlaroot/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml
//joomlaroot/components/com_users/models/registration.php
//joomlaroot/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php
//joomlaroot/components/com_users/controllers/registration.php
```

For Client Registration I have to add a view file in this component.

How can I add that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another layout within:
`//joomlaroot/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/your_file.php`

And switch to this layout at the
`//joomlaroot/components/com_users/controllers/registration.php` with:

```
$view = $this->getView('users', 'html');
$view->setLayout('your_file_name');
```